# Scala Spark Read from AWS S3 - com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently trying to do a simple read from an S3 bucket I've set up, using Spark 3.0.0 (implementation via Scala 2.12.10). However, I am receiving this error when submit the script:

```
No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : 

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

I'm implementing the current spark script:

```
package org.knd

import scala.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, SQLContext}
import io.delta.tables._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("covid-delta-lake")
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
      .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
      .getOrCreate()

    val aws_access_key = scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("AWS_ACCESS_KEY", "notAvailable" )
    val aws_secret = scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "notAvailable" )

    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", aws_access_key)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", aws_secret)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")

    print("\n" + "====================HERE====================" + "\n")

    val data = spark.read.parquet("s3a://[url-to-my-s3]/*.parquet")
    data.show(10)


  }

}
```

I've double checked my AWS keys and s3 URL, so I'm certain those aren't the issue. I've tried reading from other buckets and am receiving the same error. I've included my POM file below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.knd</groupId>
  <artifactId>delta-lake-scala</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <inceptionYear>2020</inceptionYear>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.12.10</scala.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
      <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>

    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: the environment variables you are using and the scala properties are slightly different than what is recommended here: did you try changing your environment variables and/or hadoop configuration to match: http://www.infoobjects.com/2016/02/27/different-ways-of-setting-aws-credentials-in-spark/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://www.infoobjects.com/2016/02/27/different-ways-of-setting-aws-credentials-in-spark/), you can set environment variables using these keys

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

or set the following hadoop configurations:

```
fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId
fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey
```

These are different than the environment and keys you use.

Comment: So I set the hadoop configurations using this:


`
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", aws_access_key)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", aws_secret)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
`


inside the spark script itself. The script also retrieves the keys from environment variables that I set on my machine, and I validated to make sure they're the correct values. I've also  hardcoded the keys to the hadoop configurations, and I still experience the same error.